# Edit line names with a new name containing an incremented value

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, fasta

This seems like a simple task to me but getting it to work easily is ending up more difficult than I thought:

I have a fasta file containing several million lines of text (only a few hundred individual sequence entries) and these sequence names are long, I want to replace all characters after the header `>` with `Contig $n`, where `$n` is an integer starting at 1 and is incremented for each replacement.

an example input sequence name:

```
>NODE:345643RD:Cov_456:GC47:34thgd
ATGTCGATGCGT
>NODE...
ATGCGCTTACAC
```

Which I then want to output like this

```
>Contig 1
ATGTCGATGCGT
>Contig 2
ATGCGCTTACAC
```

so maybe a Perl script? I know some basics but I'd like to read in a file and then output the new file with the changes, and I'm unsure of the best way to do this? I've seen some Perl one liner examples but none did what I wanted.

```
$n = 1

if { 

    s/>.*/(Contig)++$n/e

    ++$n
}
```

Comment: Do the header lines really start with a backslash, and is every other line blank like that?

Comment: no, I was having trouble, the browser keep thinking I was typing code, the lines start with the ">" symbol and there are no empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^\\>/{$0="\\>Contig "++n} 1' file
\>Contig 1

ATGTCGATGCGT

\>Contig 2

ATGCGCTTACAC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open (my $fh, '<','example.txt');
open (my $fh1, '>','example2.txt');

my $n = 1;

# For each line of the input file
while(<$fh>) {

    # Try to update the name, if successful, increment $n
    if ($_ =~ s/^>.*/>Contig$n/) { $n++; }

    print $fh1 $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not awk expert (far from that), but solved this only for curiosity and because sed don't contain variables (limited possibilities).

One possible gawk solution could be

```
awk -v n=1 '/^>/{print ">Contig " n; n++; next}1' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -pe 's/>.*/">Contig " . ++$c/e;' file.txt
```

Output:

```
\>Contig 1
ATGTCGATGCGT
\>Contig 2
ATGCGCTTACAC
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Understandable, I am parsing some output from a genomics assembly algorithm which created sequence contigs with complex long names.  These complicated sequence names confound another algorithm i am using to annotate the sequences, so i am converting the names to something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `/e` modifier, Perl expects the substitution pattern to be a valid Perl expression. Try something like

```
s/>.*/">Contig " . ++$n/e
```